# Where I can lease a Dedicated Server, and own them after 12 month renting

Tags: dedicated-server

Do you know where I can rent Dedicated Server, and after 12 month, I get it free.

Comment: Finance the server. Do a 12 month lease with a penny buyout option.

Comment: Product recommendations questions are off-topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq), and on [StackExchange generally](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/qa).

Answer (score 2):

If you want it hosted in a datacenter somewhere, you probably won't find many of the companies that lets you own the server after a year. However! By renting the server, which is usually really cheap, you get full hardware replacement support for the full amount of time you have it (in most cases).

You could also choose to go co-located and then buy the server from e.g. Dell. You should grab your phone and give Dell a call and ask them for a 12-month instalment plan.

Remember, that if you want the server hosted anywhere, you will still need to pay for this after the lease has run out. Usually the colo price is not very far from the price including the server. There are different reasons for that.

Some of them being that by keeping the hardware standardized, offering the service on it without letting customers into the area, the datacenter saves space and money on security facilities, as only their own technicians has access to the server halls.

In a colo facility, they spend way more money on making sure that they have various types of racks and shelves to fit both rack and tower servers. Also the security facilities are much more expensive, such as making sure that customers are not able to touch other customers' equipment.